# Platform diving - diver standing position

Tags: technique, olympics, diving

I am following the Olympic diving.

I am always wondering why or how divers choose to jump from different positions on the platform (i.e not from the center)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule governing where a diver should stand before diving. They can choose any place or position they like. According to the linked [Wikipedia article on **diving platform**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_platform):

> Diving platforms for FINA sanctioned meets must be at least 6 metres
>   (20 ft) long and 2 metres (6.6 ft) wide.

The width is necessary because there is also a [synchronized platform diving competition](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=team+diving+Olympics&mie=oly%2C%5B%22%2Fg%2F11c3ymwgt6%22%2C6%2Cnull%2C2%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C10%5D).